# jQuery time picker and MVC 4 validation - the field must be a date

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, timepicker

I am using this jQuery plugin to select a time: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

I init my timepicker like this:

```
$('#scheduletime').timepicker({ 'scrollDefaultNow': true, 'timeFormat': 'h:i A' });
```

which results in the time being displayed in the following format:

```
08:00 AM
```

I am using MVC client side validation, and my model looks like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
public DateTime? ScheduleTime { get; set; }
```

My problem is I get a client side validation error:

> The field ScheduleTime must be a date.

What's going wrong? The string validation format appears to be correct, however its not working.

Comment: Is DisplayFormat the only data annotation attribute you have on your ScheduleTime property?

Comment: @ataravati I also have [Display(Name = "Scheduled time")]

Answer (score 4):

Use a DataType attribute in your Model like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
[Display(Name = "Schedule Time")]
public DateTime? ScheduleTime { get; set; }
```